# URL encoding exception

Tags: java, android, url, android-intent, encoding

I am trying to encode a URL using **UTF-8** and then launch the browser.Below is my code

```
if(URLUtil.isValidUrl(url)){
                            //if(Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(url).matches())   {

url = URLEncoder.encode(url,"UTF-8");
Intent launchUrl = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));

System.out.println("encoded new url is "+url);

System.out.println(" launurl is "+launchUrl);

mContext.startActivity(launchUrl);
}
```

I am getting an exception Activity Not Found.When i remove/comment the encoding line it works fine for me.Pattern matching also not working.

Please help below is the ouput

encoded new url is `http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F%23output%3Dsearch%26amp%3Bq%3Dnexus`

launurl is `Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://www.google.com/#output=search&amp;q=nexus`

Input URL is `http://www.google.com/#output=search&amp;q=nexus`

Comment: Problem is my URL is not fixed.I just gave an example URL.URL can belong to search engine or any other webite.Any valid website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of encoding whole url with parameters you should encode parameters values then append in url as:

```
String str_url= "http://www.google.com/";

String str_parms="#output="+URLEncoder.encode("search","UTF-8")+
                                   "&q="+URLEncoder.encode("nexus","UTF-8");

String str_final_url=str_url+str_parms;
```

Comment: Also, see this answer for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding/10786112#10786112

Comment: Problem is my URL is not fixed.I just gave an example URL.URL can belong to search engine or any other webite.Any valid website.

Comment: @AnujKumarJha : ok then first extract base url and parameters name-value pairs from url then encode and pass to Intent.

Comment: how we gonna identify base URL cause every website has different address So how i  gonna extract/separate url in two part?